# Get Approval Status

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating an approval workfflow in visualstudio 2010 for sharepoint 2010.
The Workflow creates a task at the beginning and then waits for approving the task. But how to check if the task is approved?

**Perhabs I describe my szebario a bit more detailed:**

- I've got a list of items that have to get reviewd after adding.
- If they get approved or declined it is a absolut decission and never should be changed
- If the item gets approved some functions should get fired
- If it gets declined a mail should be send!

**My Ideas:**

*Idea - Workflow*:

My first idea was to create a workflow which get fired after a ListItemd added. The WF should create a task that could be reviewed. If it is positive it should fire some functions and deletes it self.

*Idea- Workflow Design:*
[image]

*Idea- Workflow Code:*

```
       public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
            public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();
            // these properties are for the workflow task that will be created.
            public SPWorkflowTaskProperties CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
            public SPWorkflowTaskProperties CreateTaskApproval_AffterTaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
            public SPWorkflowTaskProperties CreateTaskApproval_BeforeTaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
            public String CreateTaskApproval_ContentTypeId = default(System.String);
            public Int32 CreateTaskApproval_ListItemId = default(System.Int32);
            public Guid CreateTaskApproval_TaskId = default(System.Guid);

       private void createTask1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                createTask1.TaskId = new Guid();
                // Now create the approval task.
                // Set up some of the properties.
                CreateTaskApproval_TaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
                //Setting the task properties
                CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.Title = "TestTitle"
                CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.Description = "Description";
                CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.AssignedTo = @"testemail\testuser";
                CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.SendEmailNotification = false;
                CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.TaskType = 1;
                LogComment("Request Task Created.");
            }
         private void onTaskChanged1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
//!!!! The Problem is here at Status
                    // Check to make sure the field is there on the item.
                    if (CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.ExtendedProperties["Status"] != null)
                    {
                        // Evaluate the value of the field.
                        if (CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.ExtendedProperties["Status"].ToString() == "Approved" || CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.ExtendedProperties["Status"].ToString() == "Declined")
                        {

                            TaskApproval_ApproveComplete = true;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TaskApproval_ApproveComplete = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This should never happen because there is a default, but always good just in case.
                        TaskApproval_ApproveComplete = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TaskApproval_ApproveComplete = false;

                    LogComment(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            private void completeTask1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                workflowProperties.Item.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
    //Fire some code

            }
```

Idea - Workflow- Problems:
I can't get the tasks moderation status at all. ("approved" and so on)

```
CreateTaskApproval_TaskProperties.ExtendedProperties["Status"]
```

Does any on know how to?

Comment: I'd suggest you stick to -one- stackexchange site, in this case sharepoint.stackexchange.com. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: "Duplicate" of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40678/diasable-approvement-for-a-single-listitem

Comment: Sorry but I had a bit simmilar question yesterday without an result! Thats why I've tried to look for an other solution (as I wrote in my question on sharepoint.stackexchange)! After an answer of an User I discribed my problem more detailed. So I added the details here too, because the could be usefull here too.

Comment: If you feel you need to have two questions to describe the same problem, then your question still needs a bit of work. =) In the future, stick to one stackexchange site. You're not the only one to benefit from answers, after all - future readers will need to look in several places to find solutions. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can get task status after change - from AfterProperties of your task (created in designer). Then you must use handler "Invoked" of onTaskChanged1 to get to your AfterProperties object and get ExtendedProperties["isApproved"] to see task approval.

Example method:

```
    private void Invoke_Task1_TaskChanged(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        Task1_IsCompleted = bool.Parse(task1_AfterProperties.ExtendedProperties["isFinished"].ToString());
        Task1_IsApproved = bool.Parse(task1_AfterProperties.ExtendedProperties["isApproved"].ToString());

        if (Task1_IsCompleted)
        {
            ManagerReason = task1_AfterProperties.ExtendedProperties["ManagerReason"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If tried your idea! But I alway get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception!

Comment: Then look at where it happens, and check for null, applying the appropriate flow of logic to resolve IsCompleted or IsApproved based on that.

Comment: For what object you have this exception? Did you specified After and Before Properties in designer?